# How Not To Lose Changes in TFS GIT When Using Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently working on a team with 5 other developers in various places around the world.  It's the first time most of us have used TFS (it's 2018 if that matters) Git before and we're running into some problems where when syncing changes (we're working on a single branch), some changes are lost (It's more like reverted, since you can see the history, but it feels like it's lost).  Twice in the past two weeks we've had the issue and it's happened with multiple people, so not just one person is to blame.  The best that I can figure out is that people are merging incorrectly.  Does anyone know what's going on and how to prevent it?

[image]

Sometimes there are Merge Branch commits that don't appear to have any changes in them when you look at the history.  The problematic merge is the 0de86be9 commit.  It happened to undo all changes that had happened up until that point for a few days for everyone.  So when users sync'd they lost all changes that had been committed since the older parent of the merge (basically the line that goes to the right of the main branch on the 6db5d074 commit)

If I look at the commit in TFS/VS, I only see a single file changed:
[image]
[image]

But when I use the drop down to select a diff to Parent 2, it shows changes that undo commits that have been made previously:
[image]

I'm at a loss, and I'm not sure what some are doing that is causing this issue, and therefore, what to tell them to do.

Comment: What do you do when a merge conflict occurs? The situation you describe can happen when you choose "take mine" for all files with a merge conflict, essentially discarding the other version and using your version as the file to be committed.

Comment: @Stijn One time I brought the changes back to a known good version locally, then manually applied all of the changes.  Another time, someone had a merge conflict when they attempted to sync, so we manually backed up the changes on their machine, sync'd everything, taking the server version in the conflict, then re-applied the backed up changes by pasting them over the version from the server.  So do I need to continually ask that if asked to take mine, that they undo, stash, get latest, and then apply and handle the discrepancies?  There is nothing in VS that would auto take mine is there?

Comment: You're supposed to resolve the conflicts by hand. For example, if you change a certain line that the other commit also touches, you need to tell VS which line to take or even modify the line by hand. I don't usually merge with VS though, so I can't explain in detail. (instead I use SourceTree)